# How do you import the ML Kit Object Detection library in Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode, object-detection, google-mlkit

As per this link, I'm able to install the podfile just fine: https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/object-detection/ios#objc

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqkFZ.png

But what's the actual import statement at the top of my code? I can't find that anywhere. For example I'm trying to find something like the following code example but can't anywhere.

```html
import GoogleMLKit
import GoogleMLKitObjectDetection
```

I must be missing something very simple.

Answer (score 1):

In the example projects on Github the implmentation is

```
import MLKit
```

Here are differents example projects about its use. The link is in the documentation you shared.

https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/tree/master/ios/quickstarts/vision

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Much appreciated.